# Particle animation inside transparent object

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, bezier-curves, transparency

I am new to Blender and I'm currently working on creating particle animations that follow a curve using Particle System Emitter and a Bezier Curve. The particles are rendered as Halo.

[Animation removed for IP rights]

However, I would like to locate this particle animation inside an object (with a Transparent Shader material) and I want it to be seen through the object in render. I have moved the emitter and the Bezier Curve inside the object, but when I switch to render view, the particles from the emitter are not showing inside the object even though the object is transparent.

[Animation removed for IP rights]

Here's the material setup that I'm currently using for object enclosing the animation:

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: please show us your material setup (shader nodes) or your material settings (blend mode)

Comment: How are you rendering this, EEVEE? Without raytracing, real time rendering has limited support for transparency, you may need to use something more robust for this like Cycles.

Comment: I am using Cycles with GPU Compute.

Comment: Particles have to be objects if you want to see them in render. Halos are only shown in the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easy i wouldn't render it as Halo but as icosphere. Then just give the icosphere a white color and shade it smooth and change the scale and it will look like halo.

Then you can give your transparent material a node setup like this:

[image]

and you get this:

[image]

you can checkout the blend file here: [image]

[image]

Comment: I will try this solution, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If you have problems, just write here in the comments. Then I will improve my answer.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad, i could help